# Multiple button without repeating onClickListener

Tags: android

I am making a calculator app and for every button, i have to write  button.setonclciklistner
I  am tired of initializing the button after that on click method
please don't answer to implement on click method I already know that but is there any other method

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear what the question is and you haven't included any code, what you've tried doing so far, what you are trying to accomplish, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is an option. If you do a calculator the `gridView` is perfect for that. Instead of making tons of `onClickListener` you can achieve that by multiple `cases` like in this [example](https://www.programmersought.com/article/51414350616/) shown.

Comment: Now that is what I asking for great one more helpplease, for multiple buttons we have to use this type of grid

Comment: Exactly. You can use that I mentioned. I think it is explained good enough in the example. Ask your question more specific if you have some to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the functions from my own calculator based app:

```
//normal backspace
    private fun backSpace() {
        form.bs.setOnClickListener {
            inputField.text = inputField.text.dropLast(1)
            UtilityMethods(context).playClick()
        }
    }

    //long pressing the backspace will clear input field instantly
    private fun longPressBS() {
        form.bs.setOnLongClickListener {
            inputField.text = null
            true
        }
    }

    //numeric keys are invoked here
    private fun theNumericPad() {
        for (i in 0 until 10) {
            val resID = context.resources.getIdentifier("n$i", "id", context.packageName)
            form.root.findViewById<Button>(resID).setOnClickListener {
                if (inputField.text.toString() == "0") {
                    inputField.text = ""
                }
                if (inputField.text.toString() == ".") {
                    inputField.text = "0."
                }
                inputField.append(i.toString())
                //clear custom type
                if (!form.rb00.isChecked) {
                    form.ctField.text = ""
                }
                //play sound
                UtilityMethods(context).playClick()
            }
        }
    }

    //the dot
    private fun dot() {
        form.dot.setOnClickListener {
            if (inputField.text.toString() == "") {
                inputField.append("0.")
            } else {
                inputField.append(".")
            }
            //clear custom type
            if (!form.rb00.isChecked) {
                form.ctField.text = ""
            }
            UtilityMethods(context).playClick()
        }
    }
```

And the function to play key tap sound is:

```
//play sounds
    //normal key tap sound
    fun playClick() {
        val am = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, 1f)
    }
```

Also to make it easy to understand, variable like form is the view binding of you keyboard layout.